# how to get channel variable: SIPUserAgent with AMI?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

Is there any AMI function to get UserAgent variable for any SIP channel?
I tried "Getvar" but got empty value.

ps. I used asterisk 13.18.5

```
Action: Getvar
Channel: SIP/2000-0000003c
Variable: SIPUSERAGENT

Response: Success
Variable: SIPUSERAGENT
Value:
```

Answer (score 1):

SIPUserAgent is **FUNCTION**.

And yes, it is not same as SIPUSERAGENT

In modern versions you should use

```
SIP_HEADER(UserAgent)
```

Comment: I'm not querying UserAgent in dialplan. I'm querying UserAgent in AMI. And, I can not find the "SIPUserAgent" function in manager client document. (https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+AMI+Actions)

Comment: Yes, but it is case-sensitive as all actions in AMI.